# Post and Get via CURL

Tags: php, url, post, curl, get

I'm trying to send information from a form and a hidden email variable (from a db) to a PHP script using cURL. I have the post items moving correctly, but I am not sure if can also send a variable vai the url. (the $_Get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard querystring should work.

Comment: It looks like this would work. I'm thinking about appending onto the add post query string with code like this

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST).'&Email='.$qst['lpemail']);

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling the vars from $_REQUEST, which if i remember correctly is basically $_GET which is then overwritten by $_POST and then $_COOKIE.

Comment: That is a big no no in my book. Try using register_globals = on, that might simplify the process even more! =))